# CSS: Why does adding -webkit to linear-gradient() effect the angle of the gradient on Chrome?

Tags: css

Just experimenting with CSS, I've noticed that on Chrome browser adding:

```
html {
   background-image: linear-gradient(65deg, #A683E3 50%, #E4E9FD 50%);
}
```

results in a much steeper gradient than:

```
html {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(65deg, #A683E3 50%, #E4E9FD 50%);
}
```

Most documentation I see only refers to linear-gradient (rather than -webkit-linear-gradient) and I can't see linear-gradient listed on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/WebKit_Extensions.

Is it best to just stick to not using -webkit prefix?

Comment: If you set it to 0deg, and you can see that -webkit-linear-gradient is a left-to-right gradient, while linear-gradient is a top-to-bottom gradient, so it might be because they have different starting points..

Comment: you need to use the first one, but consider adding min-height:100% to the html